# Subsetting data that do not have missing values in multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a large dataset with hundreds of colums and thousand of rows. I want to select and create another dataset that has no missing values in multiple colums.

i.e

```
A  B   C   D   E
1  3   2   2   2 
2  NA  3   1   2 
3  NA  2   1   2
NA 2   NA  1   NA
```

I want to get rows that do not contain NAs in column A, B, C.
how can I do that? Thank you

Comment: Try `df[complete.cases(df[, 1:3]),]`, where `1:3` corresponds to the numeric index of columns `A` to `C`